# Cheerio: Is there anything like endsWith for a class selector?

Tags: node.js, npm, web-scraping, cheerio, jsonframe-cheerio

I am trying to extract all the links on a webpage whose class name ends with `-name`.

```
console.log($('a.-name', html).text().trim());
```

Is there some way like regex to achieve the same?

```
console.log($('a.*-name', html).text().trim());
```

Comment: Just `$('a[class$="-name"]')` will work

Comment: That's a more better solution. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your comment :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`[class$="-name"]` syntax](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to find a class attribute that ends with `-name`.  You can then filter the matches to only those that are also `a` tags.

```js
console.log($('[class$="-name"]').filter('a').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="foo-name">foo-name</div>
<div class="nothing">nothing</div>
<div>
   <a class="fee-name" href="/">fee-name</a>
</div>
```

But, since this is a raw attribute search, it won't work if there are other class names on the same tag and they are after the one you are targeting.

To cover that, I don't see any built-in way to do it.  You would probably have to collect all `a` tags and then write your own filter function to examine the class name attribute with your own code.